# ImportError: cannot import name GEOSGeometry Django 1.7

Tags: geodjango, django, heroku

I am a heroku newbie and I keep getting the said error whenever I try to sync db on heroku. I am using a hobby Dev instance which from this [link](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) shows that their is no support for PostGIS on the free database.

I believe the problem is the missing [geolibraries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/) however me being new to heroku, could be I missed a step in installing them.

Below is my stacktrace:

```
Running `python manage.py dbshell` attached to terminal... up, run.7391
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 23, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.options import GeoModelAdmin      # NOQA
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/options.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.widgets import OpenLayersWidget
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/widgets.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry, GEOSException
ImportError: cannot import name GEOSGeometry
```

I am using the following [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use GeoDjango you need to have at least GEOS installed, which might not be the case for the standard heroku instances, and you would need to use a [custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack) that has geos and/or gdal installed. Here are two examples

https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack

https://github.com/mojodna/heroku-buildpack-gdal

However, you would still need to have a spatially enabled backend, which for heroku would be PostGIS (I think they only work with postgres). And that is only available for paid database instances.

Comment: Thaks @yellowcap. I figured as much. [This link](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) actually shows that for free instances, PostGIS is not enabled. Thanks for the info on custom buildpacks however. Much appreciated.